# How to change position of the elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program, that take 10 `Integer`s from a keyboard and list them in an array indexed from 0-9, and reports the position of the lowest number in the array. If the lowest number has any other position than 0, then the program is supposed to switch the position of the lowest number input with the number in the first position in the array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q35 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] helTall = new int[10];
        int input;

        int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0;i<helTall.length;i++) {

            System.out.println("Integers? ");
            input = tastatur.nextInt();  

            if (input < lowest) {
                lowest = input;
            }

            helTall[i] = input;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < helTall.length; i++) {
            helTall[0] = lowest;
            System.out.println(helTall[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Lowest number is " + lowest);
    }
}
```

The only problem is that instead of changing position with the lowest number with the number at `helTall[0]`, it just completely replaces the first number in the sequence `helTall[0]` with the lowest `Integer`, that way if my input is `4 5 63 23 6 -4 7 33 23 99`, then the output becomes `-4 5 63 23 6 -4 7 33 23 99` (as you can see the first input number is completely erased), but it should have been `-4 5 63 23 6 4 7 33 23 99` any tips/advice/solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of the index of the lowest number (each time you write `lowest = input;` you should add `lowestIndex=i;`.
Then `helTall[lowestIndex]` will be the lowest number.
So you swap `helTall[lowestIndex]` with `helTall[0]` instead of just overwriting the value of `helTall[0]`.

I thought it was enough to describe the solution in words, but I guess it wasn't...

```
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int lowestIndex = 0;
for(int i=0;i<helTall.length;i++){
  System.out.println("Integers? ");
  input = tastatur.nextInt();  
  if (input < lowest){
    lowest = input;
    lowestIndex = i;
  }
  helTall[i]=input;
}
// swap the numbers
if (lowestIndex > 0) {
  int temp = lowest;
  helTall[lowestIndex] = helTall[0];
  helTall[0] = temp;
}
// display output
for (int i = 0; i < helTall.length; i ++) {
  System.out.println(helTall[i]);
}
```

Comment: how do I do that? I wrote this program long time ago, and im just looking through stuff to review, and I tought I already had this one right, but I didnt, and I have forgotten a lot, do I just set it equal to each other or something?

Comment: @yyzzer1234 see udpate

Comment: didnt work, this does exactly the same thing as the program in the question..,(well more or less) if I input: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,34 I get 0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,34, I wonder why I have two 0's and where the number 3 went?

Comment: @yyzzer1234 It works. I just tried it with your input. Output was `-4
5
63
23
6
4
7
33
23
99`.

Comment: @yyzzer1234 and for your other input I got `0
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
2
34`. You probably forgot to copy/replace some of the code.

Comment: ohh yeah, you're right sorry, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: but could you please explain what the lowestIndex=i; does? :D

Comment: @yyzzer1234 It records the index in the array of the current lowest number. When the loop that find the lowest number ends, lowestIndex holds the index in the array of that number, which allows you to swap it with the first number in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < helTall.length; i ++) {
    helTall[0]=lowest;
    System.out.println(helTall[i]);
}
```

First, you do not need to repeatedly (10 times) put `lowest` into `helTall[0]`. Let's move that outside first so it's only done once:

```
helTall[0]=lowest;
for (int i = 0; i < helTall.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(helTall[i]);
}
```

Next, the line we put outside the loop overwrites the helTall[0] without regard for what is already in there. We need to temporarily save that number in there elsewhere, then overwrite the spot, so that we can use it to overwrite the spot where the lowest number was:

```
int numberAtLocationZero = helTall[0];
helTall[0]=lowest;
// Now, on this line we need to write helTall[lowestNumberIndex] = numberAtLocationZero;
for (int i = 0; i < helTall.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(helTall[i]);
}
```

In the above code I wrote a comment. It relies on you either knowing where in the array the lowest number was, or to find it again. If you add a new variable to your code that takes in values called `lowestNumberIndex` and update that each time you detect a new lowest number, then you're pretty much done if you uncomment my comment.

Comment: Did you fix what I say at the last step? Show updated code please.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate variable to store what is in the bottom of the array before you overwrite it with your new lowest input number.

```
helTall[0]=lowest;
```

should be proceeded by

```
int placeholder = helTall[0]
```

and followed by

```
hellTall[i] = placeholder;
```

This way, you'll end up swapping the two array elements, the first swapped with the lowest. Is this what you're trying to accomplish? This leaves most of the array unsorted.